# How to convert string to date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know that there are a lot of questions pertaining to this topic here. However, I can't seem to solve my issue.

I have this string for example, "2013-08-26 12:11:51 10:17:25", and I only want to grab, "2013-08-26", then convert it back to a string. I have tried many methods without success:

```
NSMutableString *visitDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"2013-08-26 10:17:25"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:visitDate];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
NSMutableString *returnConvertedDateString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:(NSMutableString *)date];    
NSLog(@"converted string: %@", returnConvertedDateString);
```

The result of NSLog statement above is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument'
```

I also tried:

```
-  (NSMutableString *) convertDateToString : (NSMutableString *)visitDate{
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:(NSDate *)visitDate];
NSMutableString *returnConvertedDateString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%ld-%ld-%ld", (long)[components year], (long)[components month],(long)[components day]];
return returnConvertedDateString;
}
```

Comment: what is the result of the NSLog statements?

Comment: Is there a reason for converting to a date and back to string? From your question it seems that a simple regex extraction would do the job...

Comment: It gives an error. "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument'"

Comment: Try initiating the time string with a NSString. Like NSString *visitDate = @"2013-08-26 12:11:51"; Obviously remove the last part. Thanks @CarlVeazey.

Comment: Your input string doesn't make any sense. What date format is that?

Comment: @hajder Its still the same.

Comment: read what @CarlVeazey mentioned. Your date format is unknown. Did you perhaps forgot to remove one of the time strings?

Comment: NSDateFormatter has a stringFromDate method, if that's what you are looking to do when you type cast a NSDate* to NSMutableString*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate time in your string. Assuming it's a typo, you can get what you want like this.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-08-26 12:11:51"];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString * dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Comment: This is awesome. However, can you kindly explain to me why do we need to setDateFormat twice?

Comment: Because you use it once to make the `NSDateFormatter` recognize your string before converting it to a date object, once you have the date object you use it again to strip the unnecessary part from the date and convert it back to string. I see that most people use two `NSDateFormatter` objects for this but as you can see no need to do that since you can reuse it with different format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format of the date time string is `NSString *visitDate = @"2013-08-26 12:11:51 10:17:25";`

Try this method:

```
-  (NSString *) convertDateToString:(NSString *)visitDate{
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
  NSTextCheckingResult *firstMatch = [regex firstMatchInString:opening_time options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [visitDate length])];
  if (firstMatch) {
      NSRange range = [firstMatch rangeAtIndex:0];
      NSString *dateString = [urlString substringWithRange:range];
      return dateString;
  }
  return nil;
}
```

This method should extract only the `yyyy-MM-dd` portion of the string and return as a string representation. Remember to modify it to mutable version if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is

NSMutableString *visitDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"2013-08-26 12:11:51"];

```
    NSArray *items = [visitDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"%@",[items objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string, why not just returning the first 10 characters?

```
[dateString substringToIndex:10];
```